# Capture rows for a column in file from delete sql -Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have to capture rows for a column that was deleted. How can i do that without having to write a select query?

```
delete from myschema.mytable where currentdatetimestamp > columnDate
```

this should delete 5 rows for example

I want to capture rows of columnID (not all the columns of the table) in a file that was affected by the above
file should have

```
1234
1235
1236
1237
```

1238

Comment: What kind of "file"? Another database? A table in the same database? A text file?

Comment: **"...capture rows for a column that was deleted"**, I'm afraid you can't. Rows are *already deleted* right?

Comment: @KenWhite - yes write the data to a text file before it gets deleted.

Comment: The only way to do this would be in a DELETE trigger, as @BobJarvis says below - it is called **as** the rows are being deleted though, not after. Once they're deleted, it's too late. What are you actually trying to accomplish, though? There's probably a better way to do it than with a text file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [RETURNING clause](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/returninginto_clause.htm) of the [DELETE statement](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_8005.htm) (Adapted [this example in the Oracle Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/tuning.htm#BABHDFDE)):

```
DECLARE
   TYPE NumList IS TABLE OF myschema.mytable.columnID%TYPE;
   IDs NumList;
BEGIN
   DELETE FROM myschema.mytable WHERE currentdatetimestamp > columnDate
      RETURNING columnID BULK COLLECT INTO IDs;
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Deleted ' || SQL%ROWCOUNT || ' rows:');
   FOR i IN IDs.FIRST .. IDs.LAST
   LOOP
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('columnID: '||IDs(i));
   END LOOP;
END;
/
```

You can do whatever you like with the resulting collection of IDs.

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible to do what you want by using a DELETE trigger.  Following is an example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER MY_TABLE_DELETE_TRIGGER
  BEFORE DELETE ON MY_TABLE
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Deleted row with ID=' || :OLD.COLUMN_ID);
END MY_TABLE_DELETE_TRIGGER;
```

This is just an example - you should modify it to do whatever you need.

Share and enjoy.

Comment: I agree that would be the only possible way to do it. I'm not sure of what the purpose would be, though; since the poster didn't explain what the reason for doing so is, it's hard to say whether this is the right answer or not though.

Comment: Thanks - i want to capture those IDs because there are corresponding files on the file system that needs to be deleted as well. So i will loop through file and delete 1234.xml, 1235.xml, etc..

Comment: @Jay - perhaps you could use UTL_FILE.FREMOVE()?  The problem here is that if your transaction get rolled back for some reason, the file would be removed but the row would still remain.

Comment: @BobJarvis - i am not familiar with that. Let me read on it. Thanks!